# Compile bep-20.sol Problem On remix.ethereum.org

Tags: javascript, html, compilation, token, ethereum

```html
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol"

contract Firmspot is ERC20 {
    constructor(uint256 initialSupply) public ERC20 ("Firmspot", "FSp"){
        _mint(msg.sender),initialSupply);
    }
}
```

**I tried compiling the code above but it was unsuccessful, the error I receive;**

```html
ParserError: Expected ';' but got 'contract' --> bep-20.sol:5:1: 
|
5 | contract Firmspot is ERC20 { |
|  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**Please can someone help me out?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a syntax error. You need to end the `import` line with a semicolon.

```
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
```

Another syntax error is in your call of the `_mint()` function, there's an extra parenthesis.

```
// removed the extra parenthesis
_mint(msg.sender, initialSupply);
```

---

Also, your code is going to give a warning that the constructor doesn't need to have the `public` visibility modifier and that it's going to be ignored anyway. You can safely remove the visibility modifier from the `constructor`.

```
constructor(uint256 initialSupply) ERC20 ("Firmspot", "FSp") {
```